# boost::spirit char/string mixing

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I'm trying to get a handle on using boost::spirit to parse character tokens, and am having great difficulty.  Here is the sample code I'm working on:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
struct tok_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, string(), ascii::space_type>
{
  tok_parser() : tok_parser::base_type(start)
  {
    tok1   = qi::char_("AB");
    tok2   = qi::char_("12");
    mytoks = (qi::lit("A1") | qi::lit("A2") | qi::lit("B1") | qi::lit("B2"));
    start  = mytoks;
    //start  = tok1 >> tok2;  // error 1
    //start  = +mytoks;       // error 2
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator, string(), ascii::space_type> start;
  qi::rule<Iterator, string(), ascii::space_type> mytoks;
  qi::rule<Iterator, char, ascii::space_type> tok1;
  qi::rule<Iterator, char, ascii::space_type> tok2;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  tok_parser<string::const_iterator> g; // Our grammar
  string str = argv[1];
  string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
  string::const_iterator end = str.end();
  bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, g, boost::spirit::ascii::space, str);

  if (r && iter == end)
      cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
  else
      cout << "Parsing failed\n";

  return 0;
}
```

ERROR 1:

What I'd like to do is to create two token rules that allow me to parse all of A1,A2,B1,B2 instead of having to list out all literal permutations.  As the code is, it compiles and recognizes the target tokens.  But if I try to build my parser out of the tok1 and tok2 rules, it does not compile generating an error about type mismatches:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type âboost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >â to type âcharâ
```

I assume this has to do with trying to create strings out of chars.  I've played with any number of permutations of type guessing but have failed.

ERROR 2:

Additionally, I'd like to allow an arbitrary number of tokens to be parsed, unfortunately, prepending with the + operator does not work as expected either.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rules, attribute always need to be specified using the function declaration syntax:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, char(), ascii::space_type> tok1;  
qi::rule<Iterator, char(), ascii::space_type> tok2;
```

which should solve your compiler problems.

Wrt your permutation problem: I'd suggest to do something like:

```
rule<Iterator, string(), ascii::space_type> r = char_("AB") >> char_("12");
```

which will match 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', or 'B2'.

Creating another rule allows for the required repetition:

```
rule<Iterator, vector<string>(), ascii::space_type> rs = +r;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, spirit is quite the simple/complex/wonderful/awful library.